# how to define a pointer to function that returns a pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

How to **define a pointer to function that returns a pointer to function?**

```
typedef int(*a)(int,int);
a (*b)(int,int);
```

Why this can work,but the following can't work?

```
(int(*a)(int,int) ) (*b)(int,int);
```

or

```
int(*)(int,int) (*b)(int,int);
```

or

```
( int(*)(int,int) ) (*b)(int,int);
```

Comment: If you can, just stick with the `typedef`. Without it the syntax is wildly confusing - so much so that I don't want to attempt an answer from my phone at the risk of messing it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
int (*(*b)(int,int))(int,int);
```

You can compile the following code that demonstrates using both of the methods. I would personally use the typedef method for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addition(int x,int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int (*test(int x, int y))(int,int)
{
    return &addition;
}

typedef int (*a)(int, int);

int main()
{
    a (*b)(int,int);
    int (*(*c)(int,int))(int,int);
    b = &test;
    c = &test;
    printf(b == c ? "They are equal!\n" : "They are not equal :(\n");
}
```